# Смена стиля кнопок при мобильных разрешениях

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Необходимо, чтобы при мобильных разрешениях кнопки сменялись текстом. Есть 2 кнопки <kbd>Login</kbd> и <kbd>Sign Up</kbd>, при больших разрешениях они остаются как есть, а при разрешении менее 768 они должны меняться просто текстом. Отмена стиля через `media` не совсем удобный вариант. Думал ещё вариант с отдельным блоком со ссылками, который при маленьком разрешении сменяет кнопки. Ниже на скриншотах кнопки на больших разрешениях и как они должны выглядеть при мобильных.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="btn m-1 btn-aqua btn-md btn-block button-text" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="btn m-1 btn-aqua btn-md btn-block" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но решил проблему следующим образом:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 justify-content-center navbar-collapse navbar-collapse-1 collapse d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn m-1 btn-aqua btn-md btn-block button-text" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn m-1 btn-aqua btn-md btn-block" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Button Mobile -->

<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 justify-content-center navbar-collapse navbar-collapse-1 collapse d-xs-block">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item pb-2">
      <a href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item pb-2">
      <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

данной функцией изменишь класс тому элементу который должен выглядеть как хочешь при разрешении меньше 768

```js
function changeButton() {
  if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width < 768) {
    /*elem - это элемент которому надо сменить стили */
    elem.classList.toogle('сюда прописать название класса');
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  changeButton()
}
window.onresize = function() {
  changeButton()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот делается через js:

```
    if (screen.width() >= 768) {
        $('.имя_класса').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#имя_id').css('display', 'none');
    }
```

Есть похожая логика, но методом очистки стиля твоего фона, тени и т.д.

```
    if (screen.width() >= 768) {
        $('.имя_класса').css('opacity', ''); //оставляешь поле пустым
        $('#имя_id').css('display', 'unset!important'); //либо отключаешь стиль бутстрапа с повышенным приоритетом.
    }
```